# Java - RestTemplate 405 Method Not Allowed Although Postman Call Works

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate

I am experiencing a weird issue when working with RestTemplate. I'm using a certain REST API and there I want to update something using PUT.
Thus, in e.g. Postman I am sending this request:

```
PUT http://fake/foobar/c/123 with a certain body
```

This update via Postman is successful. If I now execute the same call in Java via a `RestTemplate`, I am getting a 405 Method Not Allowed:

```
HttpHeaders headers = createHeader();
HttpEntity<Offer> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyEntity, headers);
String url = "http://fake/foobar/c/123"; //Created dynamically, but here pasted for sake of simplicity
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(...);
ResponseEntity<OfferResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, OfferResponse.class);
...
```

I compared the URL again and again. If I copy the URL logged in the console and copy it to Postman, I can do the update successfully. I also compared the headers and everything. Everything is equal to how it is done via Postman.

Is there any potential other reason for such a behavior (another reason than I am too stupid comparing the headers etc. and missing something)? Other PUT, POST calls etc. against this API are working fine, otherwise I would have assumed that there is a general problem with my usage of `RestTemplate`

Comment: Add a logging/System.out before the new RestTemplate(...) call and output the URL generated.  Are you sure the dynamically generated URL is exactly the same as the URL you are testing with postman?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I copied the URL from there to Postman and with the exact same URL it is working in Postman

Comment: Can you show your API Code?

Comment: @MDDCoder25 Did you find out the solution for this issue? I am facing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Code `405 Method Not Allowed` means the HTTP verb (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) you use against this end-point is known but not accepted by the API.

If you can't post the details of your API as @Dinesh Singh Shekhawat suggested, I will first try to use Postman Code feature and get an automatically generated code for Java (OkHTTP or UniRest) of the request. You can find this option on the right part below the **Send** button. Copy this code and try to perform the request.

[image]

Then compare this request with yours.

You can always use `HttpPut` instead of RestTemplate if it's not a requirement:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
String url = "http://fake/foobar/c/123";

HttpHeaders headers = createHeader();
HttpEntity<Offer> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyEntity, headers);
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
httpPut.setEntity(httpEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPut);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Later I printed the request and URL in the logs.
I found that I was using a wrong endpoint.
Can you please try to print the URL and the request in the logs and check if those are expected and correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else: I was encountering the same issue and for me it was just the issue of a trailing slash `/` on the URL. In insomnia (similar to postman) I had a trailing slash, in code I didn't. When I added the slash to my code everything worked.

failure: `http://localhost:8080/api/files`
success: `http://localhost:8080/api/files/`

Of course it could also be the other way around, so just double check the actual api definition.